# In this situation, is an endless sequence of images (theoretically) formed?

Tags: optics, reflection, geometric-optics, lenses

I was dealing with an optics problem, where an object is placed at $u= -60$ cm in  front of a biconvex lens of radius of curvature $R=30$ cm and refractive index $\mu=1.5$ .
Simple calculations show that an image (real and inverted) is formed at $v=60$ cm .

This isn't what bothers me.

The curved surface of the lens facing the object also acts as a convex mirror of focal length $f=15$ cm, and produces a virtual, erect image of the object at $v_1=10$ cm.

If *this virtual image* (let's call it $I_1$) were to act as a virtual object at $u_2=10$ cm for the lens, it would produce *another virtual image* ($I_2$) at $v_2=7.5$ cm.

This process could go on, with each virtual image at $v_n$ acting as a virtual object at $u_{n+1}$ for the lens to give another image at $v_{n+1}$.

Also, each of the images formed by the **lens** could act as an object for the reflecting surface of the lens which acts as a **convex mirror**.

So that would mean an infinite string of images (in theory), of lessening brightness, yes, but images nonetheless.

### My question

Does this unending formation of images actually take place?

Or am I wrong in my assumptions somewhere?

If I am, I'd like to stand corrected.